# How REALLY do a silent installation of MS SQL 2008 R2 Express RTM - Management Studio

Tags: silent-installer, management-studio-express

I try to make a silent installation of the MS SQL 2008 R2 Management Studio Express with NSIS but I have no succeed so far.

In theory, the installer will do a silent install if I pass the `/QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SSMS /ACTION=Install` parameters, but it does not.

This parameters hide the general GUI, but the middle of the installation process the setup.exe will popup a cmd Window, and what is worse its write in it a "Success" text but the installation is not done at this point and if I close the cmd window, the setup process will fail.

[image: image demonstrate the problem]

This is the full NSIS command:

```
ExecWait '$OUTDIR\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SSMS /ACTION=Install'
```

The SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe is downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985

This parameter work when I try to install MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Are you asking how to do a silent install or are you saying the NSIS command fails but typing it in the run box (Win+R) works?

Comment: I am asking how to do a silent install correctly. (I get the same result if I run that command from cmd.) The used parameters are the official, because this installer is the "same" as the MS SQL 2008 Server R2 installer. So I dont know why this parameters do not work.

Comment: If you cannot get it to work normally then you should remove the NSIS tag, it only adds confusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an undocumented parameter **/hideconsole** which will prevent the pop up to be appear.

The code looks like this now:

```
ExecDos::exec '"$OUTDIR\binary\SQLManagementStudio.exe" /hideconsole /QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SSMS /ACTION=Install' "" "$OUTDIR\SQLManagementStudio.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the command window to appear replace your `ExecWait` with `nsExec:Exec` as below:

```
nsExec::Exec '$OUTDIR\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /QUIET  /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=SSMS /ACTION=Install'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I get errors on compile time: `Invalid command: nsExec:Exec` What I need to include to use this command?

Comment: Do you have `nsExec.dll` in your `NSIS/Plugins/x86-unicode` and `NSIS/Plugins/x86-ansi` folders?

If not then you probably have an older version of NSIS in which case I would suggest you download the latest release from here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/files/NSIS%203%20Pre-release/3.0a2/nsis-3.0a2-setup.exe/download?use_mirror=heanet&download=
then nsExec should be in place.

Comment: I have those dlls both in the `NSIS/Plugins/x86-unicode` and the `NSIS/Plugins/x86-ansi` folder. And my NSIS is up to date, I use the version 3.0a2 (I know it is alpha,but it does not matter now.)

Comment: Oh, just noticed - you've missed a colon!
It should be `nsExec::Exec` - you need to double up the colon in your command.

Comment: the cmd is still pop up

Comment: Are you installing .NET before SQL Server? Maybe if you do you can avoid the pop-up.

Comment: Yes, .Net is installed before starting the Management Console installer.

Comment: Hmm then it must be the parameters you're passing to the installer.
You might be better off with a config file - here is a quick guide, a way of approach:
http://mycodelog.com/2010/09/28/sqlsilent/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this set of options:

/Q /ACTION=INSTALL /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /HIDECONSOLE /Features=SSMS /INSTANCENAME=mssql2008R2 /SAPWD="sapass123" /SECURITYMODE=SQL